# Python if condition true for x amount of time

Tags: python, if-statement

I would like to create a condition that only gets executed if a is True for more than 3 seconds. I would like it to work like this.

```
if a == True for more than 3 seconds:
   dosomething
```

Comment: Should it wait for three seconds when this condition is reached?

Comment: Do you need your program to do something during those three seconds? If not:

I would check the condition and if true--> wait 3 seconds, which is just time.sleep(3), and then check the condition again

Comment: How could this condition possibly change from True to False? Do you have a background thread running? Or a background process? Or something?

Comment: yes time.sleep() does not work because my script stops running

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if the value hasn't change for 3 seconds.

```
import time
id_a_old = id(a)
time.sleep(3)
id_a_new = id(a)
if id_a_old == id_a_new: # assumes that a is initially true
   dosomething
```

Since bool type is immutable the object id changes if it gets changed.

If you want to check if is has changed after 3 seconds do the following. If any thread changes `a`   within 3 seconds it will capture that.

```
import time
time.sleep(3)
if a:
   dosomething
```

Comment: time.sleep() stops my script and i still need it to run

Comment: can you post the traceback?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution (motivated from Marlon Abeykoon's solution):

```
     import time
     startTime = time.time()
     while a == True:
         endTime = time.time()
         #do other stuff
         if (endTime - startTime > 3):    
             print("Longer than 3 seconds")
             break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import time 

a = True 

x = int(time.time())
xa = a


while 1:

    if a == True and xa == a and int(time.time()) == x + 3:
        # dosomething
        print "A is True for 3 seconds"
        break

    if(xa != a):
        # dosomething
        print "Value of alfa changed from %s to %s in less than 3 seconds" %(xa, a)
        break
```