# How to check if eyes are not detected for x amount of time

Tags: python, opencv, if-statement

I am currently writing a program that uses openCV with a haar cascade for eyes. I need it to run some code if eyes are not detected for a few seconds, and I can't figure out how to use the time library to check the time. Here is an example of something I have tried.

```
if len(eyes) == 0:
    if noEyeTime - startTime > 2:
        print("closed for more than 2 seconds")
        time.sleep(2)
        startTime = time.time()
    noEyeTime = time.time()
# The variables are declared outside of the while loop
```

This is the check that I've written (it's inside a while True loop), and I've tried moving around the variable updates but I can't figure out how to check if eyes have not been detected for x amount of time.

I also read this post:
[Python if condition true for x amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263299/python-if-condition-true-for-x-amount-of-time)

But the solution doesn't work for me because the program still needs to be running, so time.sleep() is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to set the timer `startTime = time.time()` before the detection instruction, and accumulate that time during the loop, until the condition(supposed to be in the while loop) `noEyeTime - startTime > 2` is satisfied, then you can return `True` or `False` or whatever result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ritesh's idea, I moved the startTime to where the eyes are detected, and then compared that to the current time when the eyes are not detected. The code looks like this:

```
# Writes to log file when eyes are detected
if anterior != len(eyes):
    anterior = len(eyes) 
    log.info("faces: "+str(len(eyes))+" at "+str(dt.datetime.now()))
    startTime = time.time()

if len(eyes) == 0:
    elapsedTime = endingTime - startTime
    if elapsedTime > 2:
        print("eyes closed for 2 seconds")
    endingTime = time.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can have a time track by creating an `starting_noEye=time.time()` before starting eye no eye detection and an `ending_noEye=time.time()` at the end of the no eye detection part of code. The noEyeTime can be assigned to differenence of those :- `noEyeTime=ending_noEye-starting_noEye`. This will give you the amount of time when eyes were not detected.